# Show a subset of $[0,1]^2$ has content $0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've been studying Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds" and I'm thinking about the following question:

> Let $C \subset [0,1]^2$ be the union of all $\{p/q\} \times [0,1/q]$, where $p/q$ is a rational number in [0,1] written in lowest terms. Show $C$ has content $0$.

What I've tried to show is that $C$ has measure $0$, since it is the countable union of sets of measure $0$, hence has measure $0$. Then I tried to show $C$ is compact, because that would imply it has content $0$, but the problem is that it isn't compact, since it's not closed; $C$ contains points of the form $(p/q,0)$ and these can be used to approximate $(\text{irrational number},0)$ arbitrarily well, but the latter clearly doesn't belong to $C$, so I'm kinda stuck. I want to show it has content $0$ probably using the definition, that is finding a finite cover of $C$ by means of closed rectangles with arbitrarily small area, but I'm not sure how to construct it. Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I'm unsure if this is actually related to Lebesgue theory, since Spviak doesn't mention it. Feel free to change the tags.

Comment: Lebesgue measurable doesn't imply Jordan measurable.

Comment: You can try to show that your set is Jordan measurable, and then calculate it's measure which you know is 0.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Ok, so all I need to do is find its boundary and show it has measure $0$, and then the set $C$ being bounded, I'd conclude it's Jordan-measurable and then calculating probably shouldn't be bad. Ok, thanks, I will try.

Comment: Perhaps give a simple description of the closure of your set.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: however, closed and Lebesgue measure zero does imply Jordan measurable.

Comment: @GEdgar I'd say every point of the set is a boundary point, since any point is of the form $(p/q,x)$ where $x \in [0,1/q]$, then it's clear by the density of the rationals that there is a point of the form $(\text{irrational},x)$ that can be made arbitrarily close, so that every point in the set is a boundary point. On the other hand, any point of the form $(\text{irrational},x)$ for some $x \in [0,1/q]$ is clearly a boundary point, again by density of the rationals. So it's closure is $C \cup \{x\} \times [0,1/q]$ where $x \in [0,1]$ and $q \in \mathbb{N}$. Is that right?

Comment: No, too much...

Comment: @GEdgar I think I see the error in my reasoning: You cannot say that $(\text{irrational},x)$ for $x \in [0,1/q]$ is a limit point unless $x = 0$, because the better you want to approximate an irrational number, the larger you want your denominator to be, and eventually to approximate it arbitrarily well, $1/q \rightarrow 0$ which means if $x \neq 0$ that point can be kept a finite distance from our set, meaning it's not a limit point. Now if I am correct, that means only $(\text{irrational},0)$ is the boundary, which is of measure $0$, hence the closure has measure $0$, hence content $0$.

Comment: correct.  Why not write up the whole thing now?

Comment: @GEdgar So, $C$ is the countable union of sets of measure $0$, hence has measure $0$, and its boundary has measure $0$, so its closure has measure $0$. Then the closure is compact, hence has content $0$, and $C$ being contained in its closure, has therefore content $0$. Ok, I really appreciate it. Thank you very much. Maybe you'd want to post any answer so I can accept it, if you'd like. :)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Can you show that, given any $\epsilon>0$, you can cover your set by finitely many rectangles in $[0,1]^2$ with total area $<\epsilon$?

Comment: This will be a good way to do it.  It doesn't require any Lebesgue theory.